# visualvm monitoring of JBoss EAP 7

Tags: visualvm, jboss-eap-7

I have a server with JBoss EAP 7 on port 8380.
I want to monitor the jboss via visualvm from my workstation.

How do I need to configure to accept the connection.

I tried it with jmx-parameters in $JAVA_OPTS and jmx over management-interface.
Nothing works.

Maybe someone has a good tutorial.

Best Regards
Christian

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/monitoring-wildfly-using-visualvm. Those instructions should work with JBoss EAP 7.

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming JBoss EAP 7.1 Performance Tuning Guide has instructions that I have also tested with JBoss EAP 7.0 (I assume you are connecting to a remote server):

- Bind the management interface to an IP address: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/performance_tuning_guide/index#configuring_remote_monitoring
- Connection steps for VisualVM: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/performance_tuning_guide/index#connecting_to_a_remote_jboss_eap_jvm_using_visualvm

Full disclosure: I am a Red Hat employee and the writer of that guide. If you have any feedback to improve the guide, I'd be more than happy to receive it.

Comment: Thank you, I found my mistakes. Can I import the jboss-modules directly into visualvm, so that I don't need a local zip archive of JBoss EAP?

Comment: @ChristianMolecki sorry, I didn't see your question before now. I haven't tested it myself, but as long as the jboss-cli-client libraries are available to VisualVM, it should work.

Comment: I copied the libraries into the visualvm-directory and wrote a batch-filed to link to the corresponding directory. Unfortunatly the steps won't work for JBoss EAP 6.4.

Comment: These links are inactive, 404 not found

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @krokodilko. The 7.1.Beta docs were removed, so I have corrected the links with the EAP 7.1.0.GA docs

Comment: Be aware that if you miss to start jvisualvm with the flags as documented above the connection to the remove server will still work and it will show some basic information but monitoring, sampling etc. will not be possible.